# Can somebody explain this?

Tags: functions

[image]

I am new to Mathematica.I just want a approximation by producing Pade approximant,but I can't understand the output result.Is there anything wrong in my code?Or do I have to arrange my function or code in another way?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please post your code so people can more easily try it out and answer your questions.

Comment: 1) Define the function using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) and not `Equal` (`==`). 2) It is good practice to `ClearAll[f]` right before its definition. 3) When you use the function after its definition, do not include the blank pattern in your variable: so write `f[x]` and not `f[x_]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Define the function using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) and not `Equal` (`==`).
2. It is good practice to `ClearAll[f]` right before its definition.
3. When you use the function after its definition, do not include the blank pattern in your variable: so write `f[x]` and not `f[x_]`.

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := -4x Log[x] / (x + 5)
Table[PadeApproximant[f[x], {x, 1, {n, m}}], {n, 2}, {m, 2}]
```

[image: output of PadeApproximant]

Comment: Your approximation are at `x == 1`  and not  at `x == 0`.  This is why I think this question doesn't deserve any comments.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.I am still learning using mathematica and please forgive silly question.

Comment: @Artes You're righty I had switched to approximating around 1 for something more interesting, and forgot to update the code, thank you for the reminder.